# CakePHP - Customizing Message

Tags: cakephp, message, customization

Is there any way to set a layout to my messages in my model code?

Here is my model:

```
var $validate = array(    
        'email' => array(        
        'rule' => array('email', true),        
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with CakePHP.  However, you have your concerns mixed up.  The Model is there for data gathering, manipulation and massaging.  The layout of the data is under the responsibilities of the View.  In CakePHP specifically the Form Helper.

For more info about how to specify your own layout for a data validation message check out:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1639/options-inputDefaults

They provide a pretty great code sample on exactly how to do this.

I also **highly** suggest you read through the whole book.  It will prove invaluable.

Edit: Answer after clarification from comment

You would create an `element` and put it in `app/views/elements`.  Should name the file using normal Cake conventions.  Let's go with `flash_error`.

You would set this up to be your HTML that you want displayed.  To make sure your message is displayed simply add this bit of PHP wherever is appropriate

`<?php echo $message; ?>`

That's step 1.

Step 2 is in your `$this->setFlash()` call pass the appropriate parameters.  So your new calls would look like this with the element we named above:

`$this->setFlash($message, 'flash_error');`

Now your setFlash messages will use the layout defined in step 1.  Wanna different layout?  Just create a new element and pass the new element name.

The setFlash() method has 2 more parameters that come in handy (particularly if you want to have multiple flash() messages on the same page).  Another link to the book:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1313/setFlash

Comment: Charles, I appreciate your words. What happens is that I know how to use different layouts for setFlash() in my controllers, but not for messages from my $validate in my model class.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1637/flashElement

Ironically enough I was the one that actually added this little snipped to the CakePHP manual.  That makes me chuckle.

Comment: Or, if you aren't using the Auth component...give me a moment and I will just edit my original answer

Comment: @user802616 If you're wanting to display model validation errors the normal 'default' Cake way see my pre-edit answer.  The Form helper is specifically setup to take these validation error messages and display that message under the appropriate form field.